# Problems with api access of Olx

Tags: python, api, scrapy

Good afternoon.

I am trying to scrape the information of each item that is found in this [link](https://www.olx.com.co/propiedades-inmuebles_c16), but when launching the requests for obtain the links where is the information that i need, i can't get them. I was inspecting the page and i see that it brings an API, but i couldn't access it. Can someone help me with this? i really don't handle very well the API's.

This is my request for verify access

```
url = 'https://www.olx.com.co/api/relevance/search?category=16&facet_limit=100&location=1000001&location_facet_limit=20&page=1&user=1776310a947x4a045a04'

headers = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language':'es-ES,es;q=0.9'
}

req = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
req.content
```

Note: excuse my english

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its work fine, just print(req.json())

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.olx.com.co/api/relevance/search?category=16&facet_limit=100&location=1000001&location_facet_limit=20&page=1&user=1776310a947x4a045a04'

headers = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language':'es-ES,es;q=0.9'
}

req = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
req.json()
```